# how to use qRegisterMetaType to register a class by string of class name?

Tags: c++, qt, metadata

I only have a string which hold the class name.

Is it possible to register that class to qt metatype only by string of class name?

Of course, since before register, `QMetaType::type(const char *typeName)` returns unknowntype since the class hasn't been register.

Comment: And the class should already been declared by Q_DECLARE_METATYPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.
Long answer: no, to register a type somewhere you need at least the type. Sounds meaningful, right?

You know my name, do you know if I'm tall or not? No, for you should see me to know that. What could a type system guess about a type from its name? Has that type a member function `foo` or not? Is it a pod or not? It cannot know that unless you explicitly provide the actual type. The name or an alias say nothing, they can only be used to retrieve it if you have registered it previously.

---

Consider the specific case of [`qRegisterMetaType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType).
One of the overloads is a function template that can be used to create an alias for a type and the form is:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Type>("alias");
```

That is, it wants to know the type for which you are declaring something.
The other overload around has almost the same form but for the fact that it doesn't accept a string.
Both of them require the type, no way to get it out of a string magically if you haven't registered it previously.

Comment: Thanks. 

So we have to use qRegisterMetaType to register a custom type first then the QMetaType::type(const char *typeName) will be able to find correct type from meta data.